# Unique static-length ID with checksum

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, hash, checksum

There are users in the database with auto-increment IDs (1,2,3,...999999). What I need is to generate a random-looking static-length (e.g. 8 or maybe 10 characters) ID from the user_id, which can be decoded back to the original ID, much like a hash function, but reversable, basically it looks like encoding/encryption. No security needed. Why I need this? The user should enter his ID in the terminal and make a small cash payment, so if his ID is 5656 and he unintentionally enters 6565 then his payment will go to 6565's account because there IS an account with such ID. But when his ID is 3783479238, where, for example, 37834792 is the encoded version of 5656 and the last two digits (38) are the checksum (to check the integrity, such things exist for bar codes or for credit card numbers), there is no way to pay for other user.

A PHP function/library would be awesome, but if you have this for other languages (c,java,whatever) or just maths function I wouldn't mind.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends all on how strong and long you want the check to be:

- most simple is the one that says that if you add all the individual numbers together, the modulo of that number is 9. This is the check that is done on creditcard numbers.
- Here in Holland the `11 check` is used on bank account numbers and social security numbers. Here is a [explanation](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elfproef), in dutch, but you get the numbers.
- On a 40 foot container there is a extra digit that gives the container number also modulo check. You have to google for that one.